# TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable eventhough I'm using LoginRequiredMixin

Tags: django, django-views

I am having a class based view

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProjectView(TemplateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = 'project.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        proj = Project.object.filter(user = self.request.user)
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['project'] = proj
        return context
```

Eventhough I'm using LoginRequiredMixin it is going to the get_context_data

And it is throing one error like this "TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin should be placed before the **`TemplateView`**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProjectView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'project.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        proj = Project.object.filter(user = self.request.user)
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['project'] = proj
        return context
```